# Stargazer: omit stars for constant only

Tags: r, stargazer

Sometimes it's tacky to include statistical significance stars for the constant term when reporting the results of a regression. Is it possible to configure `stargazer` to keep stars for the regressors, but not for the constant term?

```
fit <- lm(rating ~ complaints, data=attitude)
stargazer(fit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the answer turned out to be using `stargazer`'s `p` argument.  From there, I just needed to write a (series of) function(s) that took a list of regression fits and returned a list of vectors of p-values.  I then manually changed the p-value of the intercepts to be 1, and presto, no tacky stars on the intercept. Plus it's reproducible with no manual LaTeX editing!

```
commarobust <- function(fit){
  require(sandwich)
  require(lmtest)
  coeftest(fit,vcovHC(fit, type="HC2"))
}

getrobustps <- function(fit){
  robustfit <- commarobust(fit)
  ps <- robustfit[,4]
  ps["(Intercept)"] <- 1
  return(ps)
}

makerobustpslist <- function(fitlist){
  return(lapply(fitlist, FUN=getrobustps) )
}
```

Then in the stargazer call:

```
stargazer(fit_1, fit_2, fit_3, fit_4, fit_5, 
          p=makerobustpslist(list(fit_1, fit_2, fit_3, fit_4, fit_5)))
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use the `broom` package to convert the fit results to a data frame, and then add stars to your heart's content:

```
library("broom")
mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = mtcars)
DF <- tidy(mod)
DF$stars <- c("", "***", "***") # inspect and add manually, or automate
```

And the `xtable` package could be used to format it for LaTeX or whatever.

Comment: The default for stargazer is Latex. The OP should say why he cannot just edit the HTML or Latex output.

Comment: Manually editing the LaTeX output is a last-ditch solution (that I might end up using) but it is not ideal -- mostly because the tables are not directly reproducible from the code.